# How to deal with missing fonts when saving PowerPoint 365 presentation

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, office365

I am editing a presentation, in PowerPoint 365 app, based on some old one, probably created by some Apple user. Each and every time when I am saving changes, I see this annoying dialog:

[image]

There seems to be no way to get rid of it:

- No way to trigger font substitution (tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on each and every font and changed font of each and every element to "Arial")
- PowerPoint itself also seems to be not making any substitution<sup>1</sup>
- No checkbox to ignore and never ask again

Is there anything I can do about it? Or am I forced to see such dialog each and every time I am saving changes to this presentation?

<sup>1</sup><sub>I recall that other Office products / versions shows such dialog only once; after acknowledge file is saves with missing fonts information stripped off.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

From [Microsoft Help on Microsoft 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/some-of-your-fonts-can-t-be-saved-with-the-presentation-2ba26947-5d18-4eb3-b5a9-67a58629e1b8?ns=powerpnt&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zpp900&helpid=163719&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us), this can happen in two situations. In case of:

- an unsupported type of font, such as *Adobe PostScript Type 1* or *Apple Advanced Typography*,
- a supported type of font where permission to embed the font wasn't granted by the document creator.

In this situation to remove embedded fonts:

1. Open the presentation file.
2. Go to *File* menu, select *Options* and *Save* on the left side.
3. Under *Preserve fidelity when sharing this presentation*, clear the Embed fonts in the file option:

[image]

The next time the presentation file is saved, any embedded fonts will be removed from the file and you will no longer see above mentioned dialog box.

This, sadly, seems to be impossible for document template, so must be repeated for each and every document, where you're getting the warning dialog during save.